# NSPredicate returning all objects instead of just 1

Tags: core-data, swift, nspredicate

This is my relationship model. Round<--->>Hole.
Round can have many holes, hole can only have one round.

I want to grab a Hole object, from a particular Round. Essentially, Im trying to grab a Hole object that has an attribute that is equal to say '1'. Here is my code.

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Round") 
    var titleHoleNumEHVC:NSString = "1"
    frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY roundToHole.holeNum = %@", titleHoleNumEHVC)

    let myArray = context.executeFetchRequest(frequest, error: nil)
```

The problem is with my predicate. The predicate is returning all HOLES for some reason and not just the HOLE with an attribute value of holeNum = 1.

Am I missing something here? I just want to grab the single HOLE object where the holeNum attribute is equal to '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NSFetchRequest `frequest` should be focused on "Hole", not "Round":

```
let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Hole")
```

Then, you have two possible ways for your predicate.

1. You can set your predicate according to some property of Round:

   ```
   frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "holeNum == %@ && holeToRound.someRoundEntityProperty == %@", argumentArray:[titleHoleNumEHVC, someRoundEntityPropertyValue])
   ```

   ... where holeToRound is the opposite relationship of roundToHole and where someRoundEntityProperty is a property of Round.
2. If you already know the Round managedObject related to your NSFetchRequest, you can set your predicate like this:

   ```
   frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "holeNum = %@ && holeToRound == %@", argumentArray:[titleHoleNumEHVC, someRoundObject])
   ```

   ... where someRoundObject is the Round managedObject that you care about.

Comment: Wow...I love you. Ive been working on this for a couple days and couldn't figure it out. Thanks for being kind about your answer as well!! Question: Why was I not allowed to access a specific to-many object by using "Round" as my entity? Is this just not allowed?

Comment: Of course, you are allowed to fetch Round managedObjects with the predicate you set first. But: do your model always provides a Hole 1 for any Round object? If so, doing what you did first will always return all your Round managedObjects.